# Getting key with maximum value in dictionary? -In lua specifically

Tags: dictionary, math, lua, max

I've seen this question a few times for python but I am looking for how to do it in Lua.
I have a dictionary that looks like:

```
myValues = {
"key1":123,
"key2":43,
"key3":367, 
"key4":2
}
```

I want a function or method that gives me the key with the largest value. In this case I would input the 'myValues' dictionary and it will throw out 'key3' as a result. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Lua table syntax isn't JSON. As a Lua table, this would be

```lua
tab = {key1 = 123, key2 = 43, key3 = 367, key4 = 2}
```

To find the key corresponding to the highest value, simply loop over the table:

```lua
local max_key
for key, value in pairs(tab) do
    if max_key == nil or value > tab[max_key] then
        max_key = key
    end
end
```

This can be rewritten to be slightly more elegant using `next`:

```lua
local max_key = next(tab)
for key, value in next, tab, max_key do
    if value > tab[max_key] then
        max_key = key
    end
end
```

For performance, you might want to keep the corresponding max. value in a local variable:

```lua
local max_key, max_value = next(tab)
for key, value in next, tab, max_key do
    if value > max_value then
        max_key, max_value = key, value
    end
end
```

Comment: This completely did the job and as you say, in an elegant and efficient manner. Thank you!